# HANA: expression for input parameter to convert time string into today's timestamp

Tags: filter, view, data-modeling, hana

In SAP HANA I can use filters as SQL or Column Store expression within a modelling view (e.g. Calculation View).

I'm trying to convert the time string like 08:00:00 into timestamp which should always take today's date.

The single hana routing I've found until now is the function TO_TIMESTAMP( [, ]).

Is there any build in function for my requrement or how else would you solve this problem?

Thanks and BR.

EDIT: this is how I try to concatenate the today's date and entered time into timestamp:

longdate(string(date(now())) +string(' ')+string(time($$P_StartShift$$))+string('.123456'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HANA doesn't have a neat construction API for datetime data types.
So, this is somewhat a workaround.

The idea here is that you have the time of the day provided as user input.

With that, we can calculate the seconds since midnight, which in turn can be added to the *current_date*.

In HANA SQL this is what it looks like:

```
select
     to_time ('13:01', 'HH24:MI') user_input_time
   , current_date
  
   , seconds_between ('00:00'
                    , to_time ('13:01', 'HH24:MI')) secs_since_midnight
   
   , add_seconds (current_date
                , seconds_between ('00:00'
                                  , to_time ('13:01', 'HH24:MI')
                                  )
                 ) current_date_user_time
from
    dummy;

/*
USER_INPUT_TIME CURRENT_DATE    SECS_SINCE_MIDNIGHT CURRENT_DATE_USER_TIME 
1:01:00 PM      25/08/2020      46,860              25/08/2020 1:01:00.0 PM
*/
```